# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\log n + n^5 + e^{n^2}\right)}{n} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$, where $x_n = \frac{\sin(\log n + n^5 + e^{n^2})}{n}$.

*Demostración*: Suppose $\epsilon > 0$. We first note the $\left|\sin(x)\right| \leq 1$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\left|\sin\left(\log n + n^5 + e^{n^2}\right)\right|\leq 1$. Pick $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. For $n\geq N $, we have $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. Second note that $\frac{1}{n} > -\epsilon $. Thus, $\left|\frac{1}{n}\right| < \epsilon$. Finally,
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sin\left(\log n + n^5 + e^{n^2}\right)\right| < \epsilon.\text{ QED}$$

Feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We can use

$$-\frac1n \le \frac{\sin\left(\log n + n^5 + e^{n^2}\right)}{n}\le \frac1n$$

Comment: Oh yeah I like that. But @user, is the way I went about the problem sufficient as well or do I need to use this fact instead?

Comment: We can use squeeze theorem or this fact in the proof by epsilon-delta.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!